# Front end reload on 'Build Project' IntellIJ using SpringBoot devtools

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

In IntellIJ not long ago I was able to make changes to my html/thymeleaf files and hit 'Build Project' and Spring Boot didn't have to restart the entire app.  It would showcase the changes in my web browser (Firefox, Chrome).  I have researched and tried a variety of changes and can't seem to find the issue/error to get me back to faster, efficient frontend productivity.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-reload-static-content

Comment: This spring.thymeleaf.cache=false did not work in my application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a setting inside of IntelliJ Idea. You can see [here](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-auto-reload-thymeleaf-templates) what you need to set, and to have in a build.gradle or pom file.